# How to add a widget to systray in AwesomeWM?

Tags: awesome-wm

I want to add a battery widget to the systray. How can I do that? How does systray recognize what programs to put in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just occurred to me that this question has the `awesome-wm` tag, so ignore my X11-answer. Here is another attempt.

There is no way to add anything to a `wibox.widget.systray` from Lua code. However, you could just put a `awful.widget.imagebox` or `awful.widget.button` next to the systray in your wibar. I *think* that having another widget next to the systray like this should look just as if there was another entry in the systray.

Comment: Yes, that's probably what I will end up doing since it's too much of a hassle. The reason I wanted to add it to the systray is to keep it organized in one place. Thank you nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

It's a protocol. It's complicated. I really think that: No, you do not want to do it yourself.

Anyway, here is the specification: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/systemtray-spec-0.2.html

> How does systray recognize what programs to put in it?

The tray icon (=the program you want to write) locates the tray manager (see section `Locating the system tray`) and then requests to be docked (see section `Docking a try icon`). For this, it creates a window and this window will then be added to the system tray.

Since the above mentions XEmbed, here is its spec: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/xembed-spec/xembed-spec-latest.html